# how can I select the most updated Tid from the StartDate turns into the following Table? (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Table like this,

```
SLId    SId     TId     StartDate
1       41      1       2017-06-15
2       104     2       2017-06-16
3       113     3       2017-06-16
4       154     4       2017-06-16
5       17      1       2017-06-19
6       41      2       2017-06-19
7       104     3       2017-06-19
8       282     4       2017-06-19
```

how can I select the most updated Tid from the StartDate turns into the following Table? by using Linq

```
Sid  Tid
41   2
104  3
113  3
154  4
17   1
282  4
```

Thank You!!

Comment: db.someTable.OrderByDescending(p => p.StartDate).GroupBy(p => p.SId).Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy()` SId (which has to be unique in your result) and `OrderBy()` StartDate

```
List<int> result = items.GroupBy(x => x.SId)
                        .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y.StartDate).Last().TId)
                        .ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/iU2PHK

Answer (score 0):

If you have your dataset you can order it by the StartDate column and pick the first result like this:

```
var dataset = //fill your dataset;    
dataset.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).First();
```